# Rails -- use type column without STI?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, single-table-inheritance

I want to use a column called `type` without invoking Single Table Inheritance (STI) - I just want `type` to be a normal column that holds a `String`.

How can I do this without having Rails expecting me to have single table inheritance and throwing an exception of `The single-table inheritance mechanism failed to locate the subclass...This error is raised because the column 'type' is reserved for storing the class in case of inheritance.`?

Any ideas on how to do this?

Answer (score 144, accepted):

In Rails 3.1 `set_inheritance_column` is deprecated, also you can just use `nil` as a name, like this:

```
class Pancakes < ActiveRecord::Base
    self.inheritance_column = nil
    #...
end
```

Comment: Actually, it appears as though that changed in `rails 3.2`.  According to [apidock](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/inheritance_column/class): 'This method is deprecated or moved on the latest stable version. The last existing version (v3.1.0) is shown here.'  Thanks for the tip though!

Comment: It was deprecated in 3.1 and removed in 3.2, I think

Comment: @Batkins The `inheritance_column` reader is moved (hence "deprecated or moved" notice). The use of setting the `inheritance_column` instance variable directly is intended and is not deprecated.

Comment: Worked in rails 5.1

Answer (score 24):

You can override the STI column name using [`set_inheritance_column`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html#method-c-set_inheritance_column):

```
class Pancakes < ActiveRecord::Base
    set_inheritance_column 'something_you_will_not_use'
    #...
end
```

So pick some column name that you won't use for anything and feed that to `set_inheritance_column`.

---

In newer versions of Rails you'd set [`inheritance_column`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ModelSchema.html#method-c-inheritance_column) to `nil`:

```
class Pancakes < ActiveRecord::Base
    self.inheritance_column = nil
    #...
end
```

Comment: do i need to actually create said column in my database?

Comment: Thank you, this worked. A framework should NEVER!!!!! EVER!!!! dictate what a table field can't be named. That's supper bad for legacy data sets.

Comment: @Jon: Rails doesn't really care about legacy data or playing nice with others, Rails has too much attitude for that. You can make it behave itself with some effort but you always end up fighting a bit if you need to do something that Rails hasn't planned for (which unfortunately includes a lot of basic database concepts). OTOH, I'm a professional heretic so other Rails people will certainly be upset with me for pointing out the ideological problems :)

Comment: I think the idea is that Rails/Ruby prefer convention over configuration, so they try to optimize it for the use cases that they feel are correct.

Answer (score 22):

I know this question is rather old and this deviates a bit from the question you are asking, but what I always do whenever I feel the urge to name a column type or something_type is I search for a synonym of type and use that instead:

Here are a couple alternatives: *kind, sort, variety, category, set, genre, species, order etc.*

Answer (score 11):

**Rails 4.x**

I encountered the problem in a **`Rails 4`** app, but in **Rails 4** the `set_inheritance_column` method does not exist at all so you can't use it.

The solution that worked for me was to disable the single table inheritance by overriding `ActiveRecord`’s `inheritance_column` method, like this:

```
class MyModel < ActiveRecord::Base

  private

  def self.inheritance_column
    nil
  end

end
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Simpler version: `class MyModel < ActiveRecord::Base` `self.inheritance_column = nil` `end`. Reference: http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/ModelSchema/ClassMethods/inheritance_column

Comment: Works for me in rails 4.2.2. Perhaps you did not restart the server or spring after doing the change?

Comment: And other users might find useful the simpler version I commented. As for the reload issue, I'm not expert but it would make sense to me to have a class property not automatically reloaded without unloading and reloading the class definition.

Comment: I don't understand your reaction, I'm just trying to give a useful addition to your answer. Why are you feeling offended? I come in peace

Comment: @Benj Looks like they deleted whatever comment(s) you're referring to so now it just looks like you're arguing with yourself. ;)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do this for all models, you can stick this in an initializer.

```
ActiveSupport.on_load(:active_record) do
  class ::ActiveRecord::Base
    # disable STI to allow columns named "type"
    self.inheritance_column = :_type_disabled
  end
end
```

Comment: Or better yet - in [ApplicationRecord](https://blog.bigbinary.com/2015/12/28/application-record-in-rails-5.html).