# How to customize Rails 3 STI column name

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a class named `Post`:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
end
```

I have a class named `Question` that inheriting from `Post`:

```
class Question < Post
end
```

and I have a class named `Answer` that also inheriting from 'Post':

```
class Answer < Post
end
```

In `Post`, I have a column named `post_type_id` and its' type is `Integer`.
How do I use STI and specific column name & type to inherit from Post? `0` means `Question` and `1` means `Answer`. (0 & 1 is the value of `post_type_id` in posts table)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7134559/rails-use-type-column-without-sti

Answer (score 26):

You can change the name of the single table inheritance column like so:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.inheritance_column = 'type_column_name'

end
```

However, there is no way to cause Rails to use integers instead of storing the actual type as a string, which makes me think that this may not be a great use case for single target inheritance. Perhaps a scope would suit you better instead:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :questions, where(:post_type_id => 0)
  scope :answers, where(:post_type_id => 1)

end

@questions = Post.questions.all
@answers = Post.answers.all
```

Comment: This is a bit of nitpick but _geez_ I wish they had named this `sti_column` since everything else in Rails refers to this stuff as STI. Just wasted 10 minutes of my life confusedly looking for this, like "I think it's `sti_column` or `sti_name` (this one exists but not what I wanted)

Answer (score 11):

There actually is a way, as with all things. You can override the [find_sti_class](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Inheritance/ClassMethods/find_sti_class) method to look for your type based on an integer.

Comment: The [source for this method](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/4467b26a3e9b96756525ae7acc2b885b3ceb2194/activerecord/lib/active_record/inheritance.rb#L309) has changed from the version provided in the link.  I would not recommend overriding a private method, but instead the public method it ultimately calls [sti_class_for](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Inheritance/ClassMethods.html#method-i-sti_class_for)

Answer (score 4):

This might be what you're looking for.

http://lorefnon.me/2014/07/27/optimizing-sti-columns.html

EDIT: Updated URL (thanks @SubhashChandran)

Answer (score 0):

You will need to set your column type using self.inheritance_column
Then you will have to provide your own behavior for the following method: "sti_class_for(type_name)" which is located in this file "activerecord/lib/active_record/inheritance.rb"

so you will have to monkey patch the above file.

This is not the recommended way, you will have to make a migration and change all the values to match your class name.

Answer (score 0):

### ENUM approach:

This does not require any overriding as the value passed to the `sti_class_for` method is the enum value and if setup correctly does not require any further intervention.

```rb
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.inheritance_column = :post_type_id

  enum post_type_id: %w[Question Answer] # for simple implicit numbering based on order
    # or
  enum post_type_id: {"Question" => 10, "Answer" => 21 } # for explicit numbering
end
```

### CONSTANT approach:

This requires overriding, which is not preferred in some cases.

```rb
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.inheritance_column = :post_type_id

  POST_TYPE_ID_CLASSES = { 0 => "Craigslist", 1 => "ApartmentsDotCom" }.freeze

  self.sti_class_for(post_type_id)
    super(POST_TYPE_ID_CLASSES[post_type_id])
  end
end
```

### Other Cases:

I wanted to add some clarification that was missing from when I found this post and the answers at the time.

`self.inheritance_column` is the majority of what you will need.  However, depending on the format of that column's data you may need to format it into what ActiveRecord is expecting, or you may get something like this error:

```
from /usr/local/bundle/gems/activerecord-7.0.7.2/lib/active_record/inheritance.rb:190:in `rescue in sti_class_for'
Caused by NameError: wrong constant name frequently_asked_questions

      Object.const_get(camel_cased_word)
            ^^^^^^^^^^
```

in my case the data was in snake_case instead of CamelCase.  A simple override of the [sti_class_for](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Inheritance/ClassMethods.html#method-i-sti_class_for) method solved this for me.

```rb
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.inheritance_column = :my_column_name

  self.sti_class_for(type_name)
    super(type_name.camelize)
  end
end
```

This problem could also be solved by storing the data in the DB in the expected format, and then converting to the alternative formats when used for other purposes.  Your needs may very, so keep that in mind when deciding which way to go.

NOTE: the reason why I did not opt for the enum in my case is to avoid any unforeseen side effects of changing the DB value with and enum and because while it is possible and works, it breaks the intent of enums being [a mapping for database integers to other values](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Enum.html).

> Declare an enum attribute where the values map to integers in the
> database, but can be queried by name

There is a [blog post](https://blog.testdouble.com/posts/2019-06-03-enumerate-your-enums/) that actually makes an argument for strigifying your enums and this is mentioned in the [documentation](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Enum.html) with a word of caution about performance:

> Finally it’s also possible to use a string column to persist the
> enumerated value. Note that this will likely lead to slower database
> queries:

```rb
class Conversation < ActiveRecord::Base
  enum :status, active: "active", archived: "archived"
end
```

So once again, your needs may very, so choose accordingly.