# How to change mongoid class inheritance field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid

I'm starting a project on Rails using an already existing MongoDB database which is already in production and is being used by another node.js app, which uses mongoose as it's ODM.

I have two types of objects stored in a collection called asset. Mongoose uses the key `__t` to keep track of the object's type and mongoid uses `_type`.

Is there a way to force mongoid to discriminate document type using the `__t` key instead of `_type`?

Comment: It appears to be hardcoded in Mongoid as `_type`, so I think not.

Comment: Would this not simply follow the Active Record pattern as shown in [How to customize Rails 3 STI column name](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9454707/2313887)? Not sure since I don't have something currently available to test, but it would seem logical. If not then you can always consider changing the key used by mongoose whilst both are running. This is `{ discriminatorKey: '_type' }` for the schema options on each model.