# How to skip a method in a rails model when invoked from different controllers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rails-activerecord

I am having an active-record model `Import`

```
class Import < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_create :check_it
  def check_it
    ...
  end
end
```

I am having two controllers `User` and `Question`

```
class QuestionsController < ApplicationController
  def import_question
    @import_item = Import.new
    ...
  end
end

class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def import_user
    @import_item = Import.new
    ...
  end
end
```

I want to skip the `check_it` method in the `Import` model for `UsersController`.

Please help..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is, do you really want to do this?

I don't know that the `check_it` method does, but I think a better way would be to simple call `check_it` if you need it, for example:

```
 @import_item = Import.new
 @import_item.check_it
```

This makes your code more explicit, and less "magical".

If you really do want to do this, you could do this in your model:

```
attr_accessor :skip_check_it
before_create :check_it, unless: -> { @skip_check_it }
```

And then create it like so:

```
@import_item = Import.new
@import_item.skip_check_it = true
```

Comment: I am getting the following error: ActiveModel::MassAssignmentSecurity::Error at /questions/import Can't mass-assign protected attributes: skip_check_it.                  Thanks @Carpetsmoker

Comment: @RahulV I didn't test it with Rails 3, but this works with Rails 4. According to [this page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10574957/activemodelmassassignmentsecurityerror-cant-mass-assign-protected-attribut), using `@import_item.skip_check_it = true` should work in any case.