# A model attribute named "type" is automatically inserted into ActiveModel::MassAssignmentSecurity::BlackList

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I do NOT have `config.active_record.whitelist_attributes = true` in application config. And I have `attr_protected()` in the model class. However, I notice that the `id` and `type` attributes are automatically inserted into `ActiveModel::MassAssignmentSecurity::BlackList`. This makes sense for `id` attribute since we do not want to set `id` in a mass assignment, but why this is also true for the `type` attribute?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The attribute `type` is used by active record when you are using single table inheritance between active record models, that's why it's in the black list. It holds the name of the class that was saved so Rails knows what kind of object was saved.

Comment: Does this mean I should not use a column named "type" in the database?

Comment: Yup, you shouldn't. Also, `type` is used to return the `Class` instance of your object, so not even Rails should be using it ;)

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7134559/rails-use-type-column-without-sti) suggests to use `set_inheritance_column` to give this magic column a different name. Is it safe to do so?

Comment: IMO, this is a really bad idea to pick such a popular name as the name of a magic column.

Comment: Yeah, bad idea, just name it something else, you might use a gem/plugin/whatever that doesn't respect that config and it could trip you up.