# How to add extra field in devise auth rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, authentication, devise

I'm doing auth with devise. I need also extra field name and type of user. Here is migration:

```
class AddColoumnToUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
        add_column :users, :name, :string
        add_column :users, :type, :string
  end
end
```

And then registration field

```
  <%=simple_form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name), :html => {:class => 'form-horizontal' }) do |m| %>

              <%= m.input :name%>
              <%=m.input :email %>
              <%=m.input :password %>
              <%=m.input :password_confirmation %>

          <%=m.button :submit %>


    <% end %>
```

All works fine, but after reg if i tried to welcome user by name got empty or error.

I do like this in profile

```
<%= current_user.name %>
```

The error is no method error or if i add @ just return empty field. Can anyone help?

Comment: [Don't use the `type` as column name, if you not use `STI`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29663933/2057388). Could you show error trace?

Comment: Please share the error trace

Comment: http://joxi.ru/82QY9DxFoGyO2d.png @SatyaKalluri

Comment: @DamirNurgaliev it is not saying the `name` is nil, it is saying that the `object` is nil. Can you share more code?

Comment: @Gerep if i write current_user.email all works fine. What u want to see?

Comment: Seems like your `current_user` is not logged in

Comment: @DamirNurgaliev have you added the `name` and `type` to the strong parameters list?

Comment: @DamirNurgaliev and also keep in mind that `type` is a restricted word, you need to change it to something else

Answer (score 1):

You have to override Registration controller of devise

First create one controller file as `app/contollers/registrations_controller.rb` And write below code in that file

```
    class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController

      private

      def sign_up_params
        params.require(:user).permit!
      end

      def account_update_params
       params.require(:user).permit!
      end
    end
```

OR instead of permit! you can add parameter like this

```
params.require(:user).permit(:name, :type, .......'other user paramete')
```

And final change in your routes file like below

```
devise_for :users, controllers: { registrations: 'registrations' }
```

Comment: you have write above routes instead of 'devise_for :users' otherwise its will be duplicate .. so write once time only

Answer (score 0):

Add in your application controller

```
before_action :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?



protected

  def configure_permitted_parameters
    registration_params = [ :name, :type, :email, :password, :password_confirmation ]
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) {
      |u| u.permit(registration_params)
    }
  end
```