# FactoryGirl populates type column with zero or nil instead of string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, factory-bot

I have a `:topics` table with a `type` column for singe table inheritance. One of my valid topic types should be the string "Announcement". I can't figure out how to build a valid factory when my validation in **topic.rb** is:

```
validates_inclusion_of :type, in: ["Announcement"]
```

When my factory is this...

```
factory :topic
  group
  membership
  type Announcement
end
```

I get this in my spec errors:

> ...type: nil... Type is not included in the list

Here is my test:

```
it 'should build a valid factory' do
  topic = FactoryGirl.build(:topic)
  expect(topic).to be_valid
end
```

FactoryGirl seems to like the class name Announcement instead of the string "Announcement", as other tests pass that way. But when I switch to the string for good measure:

```
factory :topic
  group
  membership
  type "Announcement"
end
```

I get the same error, except

`type: 0` instead of `type: nil`

Should I use the string or the class name? Any idea why my factories are getting 0/nil values?

Comment: I'm pretty sure ```type``` can't be used as a column name on a table. At least not without some sort of intervention

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first commenter is right, you cannot easily use the `type` column in Rails because it is used for single table inheritance (STI).

If you insist to use the type column then you'll need to disable the STI feature.

See [Rails -- use type column without STI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7134559/rails-use-type-column-without-sti)

Comment: I'd like to use it for STI

Comment: Then you don't need to validate your type column it will be automatically filled out from the class name.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried specifying the subclass?

```
factory :topic, :class => Announcement do
  group
  membership
end
```

I'm pretty sure that will work.