# use type column without STI in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, single-table-inheritance

I am working on the scenario which is different and I have model structures like

This is my main model which has `STI` and working fine.

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  # table is "posts" as per default behaviour
  # have column "type"
end
```

This is my another model is `FakePost` (looks weird but required :( ). This is totally clone structure of `Post` model. These objects will be become `Post` object as per requirement.

My problem is to keep `type` column in `FakePost` but should not use STI.

What I tried is below solution as per [Rails -- use type column without STI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7134559/rails-use-type-column-without-sti)

```
class FakePost < Post
  self.table_name = 'fake_posts'
  private

  def self.inheritance_column
    nil
  end
end
```

Above solution doesn't work. Because it is running the below querie

```
irb(main):001:0> FakePost.first

  FakePost Load (1.0ms)  SELECT  "fake_posts".* FROM "fake_posts"  WHERE "fake_posts"."type" IN ('FakePost')  ORDER BY "fake_posts"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
=> nil
```

What I want is that `type` based queries shouldn't run.

Is there any solution what I can do.

Because I can rename the column but when I convert `FakePost` object to `Post` object then I can't directly use `dup`.

Please let me know if I am not much clear and need more information.

Comment: You can try not to inherit your `FakePost` from `Post`. Inheritance should be used for specialization, not for sharing functionality. You can share functionality with model concerns or something like that. This should disable  STI in your case. :)

Comment: Nice suggestion but there is not option(window) to make such changes, I tried to disable STI but seems not working.

Comment: Also, it's not well documented, but you can use `#initialize_copy(copy)` if you need to do stuff while calling [`dup`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Object.html#method-i-dup). It gets called on the original and passed in the new copy

Comment: @SimpleLime, I didn't get you, can you explain what exactly you targeting?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure I followed this question but you mentioned in it "I can rename the column but when I convert FakePost object to Post object then I can't directly use dup." So if the only reason you weren't doing that was so you could call `dup` on a FakePost to make it into a normal post, you can set up an `initialize_copy` method that kind of "post-processes" the new copy during the copy process. So you can still just call `dup` and have extra stuff take place

Comment: @SimpleLime, thanks  I got your point, let me try.

Comment: @SimpleLime -  Not working, initialize_copy doesn't called by `dup` and dup don't expect params.